# Google Books inconsistency between https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/ and http://books.google.fr/books

Tags: json, http, google-api, google-books, isbn

I am writing an application where I need to find the google volume id from ISBN. When I query google books API with query
https://books.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn:
in many cases it works fine. But I have a bunch of books where I have the following (for example 9782070370016). For the query
https://books.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn:9782070370016
it replies that this book is unknown. OK, it might not be in Google data base...

But when I query the french site
https://books.google.fr/books?vid=ISBN9782070370016
it replies that this book does indeed exists and the Google volume id is lwb2zwEACAAJ and it is an edition of Germinal by Emile Zola

So why is it that it fails when I query Google Books API though this volume is known from Google?
I did not find a way to contact Google directly...